# Any good Profiler with CPU details for ASP.net MVC 3 Web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, profiler, cpu-usage

What are some good Profiler for asp.net mvc3 application with CPU usage details?

I have tried New Relic, Slimtune and Mini Profiler. All of them just provide what process is taking longer, but none of them actually give any insights as what is causing high cpu?

All of the above profiler did good job and we improved the process and now it no longer take long time to respond, it loads page in 300-500 ms, but now we're more concerned on CPU usage. Because sometimes application takes lots of high CPU very randomly, and we are trying to find what is causing this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

High CPU spikes can be for a number of reasons.

First thing I would do is determine if the 'random' high CPU is due to a Generation 2 garbage collections.

- [ASP.NET Case Study: High CPU in GC - Large objects and high allocation rates](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/06/22/asp-net-case-study-high-cpu-in-gc-large-objects-and-high-allocation-rates.aspx)
- [Investigating Memory Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163528.aspx)
- [Memory Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2tyfybc.aspx)
- [Garbage Collection and Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee851764.aspx)

There are quite a few built-in performance counters that might be helpful:

- [ASP.NET Performance Monitoring, and When to Alert Administrators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972959)

Comment: I hope this will help find the bottlenecks in application. Will try and respond. Apart from that there are any other option for profiler which we can use?

Answer (score 0):

Sam Saffron (one of the StackoverFlow authors by the way) has created a great command-line tool a while ago, but unfortunately has abandoned it.

A friend of mine forked the code to make it work in 2015:

https://github.com/jitbit/cpu-analyzer

(the page has a link to Sam's post explaining how to use it)